# What happens when multiple instances of static class are created?

Tags: java, class, static

If i re instantiate  a static class, what happens to the earlier allocated memory?

Comment: Please show us your code. Without it, the question isn't making a lot of sense.

Comment: A static class is not different from a top-level class regarding instantiation. The earlier allocated memory is still allocated to the previously created object, until this object is garbage collected.

Comment: It will load as a normal class. I guess when you mean static class, its just that you have it in some outer class with static modifier.

Comment: static inner classes are no different from ordinary classes.

Comment: do you mean a static inner class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only an nested class can be `static`. Instances of a nested `static` class behave like instances of any other class:

- an instance will be kept around for as long as there are live (i.e. reachable) references to it;
- once it becomes unreachable, it is eligible for garbage collection;
- at some point after it becomes eligible, it is garbage collected.

If you are in fact asking about a `static` reference:

```
public static Object obj = object1;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  obj = object2;
}
```

these behave like any other references.

In the above code, once you reassign `obj` to point to `object2`, this may or may not make `object1` eligible for garbage collection. This depends entirely on whether there are any surviving references to it.

Comment: More precisely, only a *nested* class can be static. An inner class is non-static by definition.

Comment: @assylias: Good point, thanks. I always forget which is which.

Comment: @JBNizet: Fair enough. Sloppy wording on my part.